# Comparing two very similar php classes (values of their attributes)

Tags: php, comparison

I have two very similar classes. Lets say Class A and Class B.

```
+---------------+      +---------------+
| Class A       |      | Class B       |
|---------------|      |---------------|
|   Name        |      |   Name        |
|   ZIP         |      |   ZIP         |
|   TelPhone    |      |   TelPhone    |
|               |      |   MobilePhone |
+---------------+      +---------------+
```

I want to compare them in the values for all common attributes.

Here's a way I tried it, but doing it for all attributes (got more than only 3 attributes) looks like a overkill for me:

```
$differences = array();

if($classA->getName() != $classB->getName()) {
    array_push(
        $differences, 
            array('name' => array(
                'classA' => $classA->getName(),
                'classB' => $classB->getName()
            )
    ));
}
// and the same code for every attribute....
```

What's the best approach here?

Additional to the handiwork, it is also not automatically updated if the classes are getting altered. For example if Class A gets also a MobilePhone attribute.

Please don't tell me, that I should do some Polymorphism, it's just an example to clarify.

I'm interested in the difference, so not only the attributes, also the values itself inside the attributes.

thanks

Comment: You should try using [Reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.reflection.php). With it, you can get a list of properties and/or methods from any class.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the sexiest thing (because of the substring to getters.., but I can't go with properties, I think sym, but I got it:

```
// getting an array with all getter methods of a class
private function getGettersOf($object) {

        $methodArray = array();

        $reflection = new ReflectionClass($object);
        $methods = $reflection->getMethods();

        foreach ($methods as $method) {
            // nur getter
            if(strtolower(substr($method->getName(), 0, 3)) == "get") {
                array_push($methodArray, $method->getName());
            }
        }
        return $methodArray;
    }


// getting an array with all differences
public function getDifferences($classA, $classB) {
        // get list of attributes (getter methods) in commond
        $classAMethods = $this->getGettersOf($classA);
        $classBMethods = $this->getGettersOf($classB);

        $intersection = array_intersect($classAMethods, $classBMethods);

        $differences = array();

        // iterate over all methods and check for the values of the reflected methods
        foreach($intersection as $method) {
            $refMethodClassB = new ReflectionMethod($classB, $method);
            $refMethodClassA = new ReflectionMethod($classA, $method);

            if($refMethodClassB->invoke($classB) != $refMethodClassA->invoke($classA)) {
                array_push(
                    $differences,
                    array($method => array(
                        'classA' => $refMethodClassA->invoke($classA),
                        'classB' => $refMethodClassB->invoke($classB)
                    )
                ));
            }

        }

        return $differences;
    }
```

Special thanks to George Marques's comment.